# SimpleDateFormat decreasing month by one when it is 00

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat originalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss");
originalDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = originalDateFormat.parse(getDate()+getTime());
```

For input 2014000513:02:44 it produces date object with value 2013120513:02:44

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the property `lenient` to false, and it will generate an error rather than subtracting one month (as there's no month `0`).

for example

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss");
originalDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
originalDateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date date = originalDateFormat.parse(getDate()+getTime()); //you'll get an error here
```